# Mysql Query for multiple counts from multiple rows in a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a query where in I want to count from multiple columns in a single query and the result should also be displayed in multiple columns  and not in same column in mysql.  Query is : count candiates sector wise . There are 2 types of sectors in same table: employment sector and training sector. I want to count candidates in both sectors.
[dataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpjtb.png)
From this data i want to count candidates sectorwise from pre_employment and training in a single query.

Comment: Please show what you have tried till now..

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY statement to group the columns in two categories and then count them.

SELECT COUNT(*), sector FROM sip_article GROUP BY sector